# Rails redis-server throws maxmemory error. Redis::CommandError (OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, redis-cli, redis-server

I'm still getting the following error message

> Redis::CommandError (OOM command not allowed when used memory >
>   'maxmemory'.):

Even after setting maxmemory to 80gb inside my redis.conf file.
When I check the value for maxmemory inside the redis cli I get 85899345920.

I'm starting my redis server with **sudo redis-server config/redis.conf**

Any help or guidance is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT 1:

**info memory** gives me:

```
# Memory
used_memory:1061024
used_memory_human:1.01M
used_memory_rss:2265088
used_memory_rss_human:2.16M
used_memory_peak:1064784
used_memory_peak_human:1.02M
used_memory_peak_perc:99.65%
used_memory_overhead:1047768
used_memory_startup:981280
used_memory_dataset:13256
used_memory_dataset_perc:16.62%
total_system_memory:17179869184
total_system_memory_human:16.00G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:85899345920
maxmemory_human:80.00G
maxmemory_policy:allkeys-lru
mem_fragmentation_ratio:2.13
mem_allocator:libc
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

**redis.conf**

```
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
dir "/Users/hugohouyez/code/hugoh1995/dogtime/dogtime"
maxmemory 80gb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

Comment: please also add `> info memory` command result here.

Comment: @ruhul just edited

Comment: `used_memory_human:1.01M` is much more lower than `maxmemory_human:80.00G` are you sure, you are connecting to this same server?

Comment: How do I know what's going on? I used to run redis-server and it would work automatically, connection to localhost:3000

Comment: Its hard to guess from here. Is there any configuration related to redis in you rails app?

Comment: none other than the default config.